# How do I set the gamma correction of a full LaTeX document?

Tags: beamer, pdftex

I will be holding a presentation with a PDF generated by LaTeX `beamer`.

Projectors in general need a gamma correction of about 2.0, however, my laptop doesn't enable me to set the gamma correction of the signal sent to a projector. So, I want to set the gamma correction or change it in the generated PDF document.

One work-around I could use in the worst case is to only change the gamma of the images, but that won't affect the other colors in the presentation.

I also tried running imagemagick on the PDF, which currently has been crunching away at it for 15 minutes without completing.

EDIT: imagemagick finally finished, but had converted everything to bitmaps. Might work as a work-around if I let it render to the full screen size, but I'm afraid that I will lose important meta-data, like page titles.

Comment: What follows is not a full answer but might help. I tend to use a toggle (from `etoolbox` package) to tweak my presentation, depending on whether it's to be visualised on a projector screen or a computer screen. Based on the state of the toggle in question, the background colour and text color are set to a suitable values. The colours of my TikZ pictures are also modified accordingly. Not a true gamma correction, I know, but that usually helps a lot.